# error using google maps api and fragmentactivity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragmentactivity

to be honest i don't know what caused the error, i am using them for the first time.
would you please help me with this.
i am only trying to start the google maps api into the fragmentActivity.
this is the logcat

```
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484): Process: com.mom, PID: 3484
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/mom/Map_activity;
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at com.mom.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:88)
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4856)
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19956)
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mom.Map_activity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.mom-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     ... 11 more
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mom.Map_activity
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):         at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):         ... 13 more
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mom.Map_activity
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):         ... 12 more
04-20 19:35:38.008: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

and this is the classes

```
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class Map_activity extends FragmentActivity {

    public static android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.location_fragment);

        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    }

}
```

and this

```
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class LocationFragment extends Fragment {

    MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // inflat and return the layout
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_fragment, container,
                false);
        mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mMapView.onResume();// needed to get the map to display immediately

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        googleMap = mMapView.getMap();
        // latitude and longitude
        double latitude = 17.385044;
        double longitude = 78.486671;

        // create marker
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps");

        // Changing marker icon
        marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));

        // adding marker
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(17.385044, 78.486671)).zoom(12).build();
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        // Perform any camera updates here
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mMapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mMapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }
}
```

and this is the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mom"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.arshad.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <!-- Permission to receive Google Maps -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.arshad.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Add"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCZdGJKBgErXwK9PP9zbG6as2ErZ__detc" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Map_activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map" >
        </activity>

        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.maps"
            android:required="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you sure this line from your manifest is correct?
package="com.mom". Normally it looks something like com.companyname.myappname

Comment: yes i'm sure. thats how i named the package

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I fixed It by adding Google Play Services library to my project. Add the following dependency to your gradle file : `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'`

Comment: i am using eclipse. is gradle exist in eclipse.
if so where can i find it.

Comment: If you are using Eclipse with ADT check out the correct way to add Google Play Services library to your project https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project (Choose Eclipse with ADT)

Comment: i hoped that would help but it didn't unfortunately.
the error is still happening although i did every thing they said.